# How do i add my bookmark function in symfony to a video

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a streaming website as a project while learning how to use symfony.

I am currently stuck trying to implement an addBookmark function to a video. I feel i've made a major mistake somewhere along the line and need some help solving this issue.

Here is my bookmarkController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Video;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Repository\VideoRepository;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Form\BookmarkType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\IsGranted;

class VideoBookmarksController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/bookmarks', name: 'app_bookmarks')]
    #[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
    public function show(VideoRepository $videoRepository): Response
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $videos = $user->getBookmarks();

        return $this->render(
            'bookmarks/video_bookmarks.html.twig',
            [
                'videos' => $videos,
            ]
        );
    }

    #[Route('/bookmarks/save', name: 'add_bookmark')]
    #[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
    public function addBookmarkRoute(
        Request $request,
        Video $video,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        VideoRepository $videoRepository
    ): Response {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(BookmarkType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user->addBookmark($video);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_bookmarks', [], response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('form/_bookmarkForm.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
            'video' => $video
        ]);
    }
}
```

My form with a button to add the video called _bookmarkForm.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">{{ button_label|default('Mettre en favoris') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And here is the video where i want to add my form to.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block title %}Origins Digital{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'home/video_recommandations.html.twig' %}
    {%  include 'home/video_tendances.html.twig' %}
    {% for video in videos %}
        {% if not video.Private or app.user %}
        <div class="modal" id="myModal{{ video.id }}">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">{{video.title}}</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <video  id="modal-player-video-{{ video.id }}" class="video-js videoPlayer" controls preload="none">
                            <source src="/uploads/videos/{{ video.videoUrl }}" alt="Vidéo {{ video.title }}" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <h3>Titre : {{ video.title }}</h3>
                        {% include 'form/_bookmarkForm.html.twig' %}
                        {{ video.description | raw }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% include 'home/genre.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

I expected this form to be added to my html code and to add any video i wanted to the user's bookmarks.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: The main problem I see is in `VideoBookmarksController::show()` and that there is not a `form` variable defined for being referenced in the `include 'form/_bookmarkForm.html.twig'` iterations, that is calling `{{ form_start(form) }}`. Assuming the template you included is `bookmarks/video_bookmarks.html.twig`